# Magento best way to integrate front-end from scratch

Tags: magento, themes, frontend

I am new to Magento development. I am assigned to the backend and integration of frontend and backend.

Our frontend developer has already made the static page using html,css,bootstrap,jquery. His work will be used as the frontend display of our project. Note that his work is not yet coded in magento style. Its just plain html and css using bootstrap and jquery.

Now i want to apply/integrate his work to my magento code. I am not sure whats the best way to do this. I read that you can create theme with Magento however i also seen that magento has its default theme.

Is the best way to do this is to create a new theme? If yes, is it compatible with the workflow we have (me doing backend, frontend developer doing frontend from scratch, then integrate)

Or is it NOT to create a theme but modify the default theme of magento and restructure/update the existing html,css so it would look the same with the work of our frontend developer.

If my question makes no sense, please enlighten me.
I have not tried anything yet since i am in study phase.

Would love to hear your experiences.

Thanks

Comment: I have been working with magento for some time now and I would say that the best way would be to create a sub-theme for the magento default theme which is already there. Do not modify the default theme as it will break everything when you update magento

Comment: @RazvanB. ok thanks for your suggestion, will follow that. 

Just wanna ask on whats the workflow of your team when doing magento frontend integration.
In our end, someone will code in frontend (from scratch, plain html,css - not magento coding style), then frontend works will be integrated to magento via creating theme.

Is this how you do it also?

Comment: Yes. However, it is much more difficult to create a magento theme from scratch. How I chose to do it was to buy a full magento theme (which included almost all the functionality I needed [magento's core]) and then create a sub-theme on that template. I don't know if you understand what I am trying to say, but long story short, you could easily create your own frontend design, building it into the sub-theme and have all the functionalities needed in your main theme.